# rtx 6000 ada vs rtx a6000

Tags: gpu, nvidia

Two graphics cards installed in one computer.

and I checked with nvidia-smi.

[image]

I ran this simple code on both graphics cards to see if it worked.

```
model = YOLO('yolov8x-pose.pt')


def pose_detection(image_path):

   file_name, ext = os.path.splitext(image_path)


   image = cv2.imread(image_path)
   height, width, channels = image.shape



   results = model.predict(image, save=False,device=0,half=True, iou=0.5, conf=0.3) 
   #results = model.predict(image, save=False,device=1,half=True, iou=0.5, conf=0.3)

   boxes = results[0].boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy().astype(int)
   print(len(boxes))




   image_path='./test12_13_0.jpg'

   for i in range(1, 1000):
      print(i)
      pose_detection(image_path)
```

I set device=0 and device=1 respectively and ran the code.

[image]

But I don't understand why this result occurs.

```
    0: 384x640 7 persons, 23.6ms
    Speed: 1.7ms preprocess, 23.6ms inference, 1.0ms postprocess 
    per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
    7


    0: 384x640 7 persons, 10.4ms
    Speed: 1.9ms preprocess, 10.4ms inference, 1.3ms postprocess 
    per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
    7
```

There is also a difference in recognition time. (The one at the top is 6000 ada.)

Wasn't the performance of the RTX 6000 ADA better than the RTX A6000? Or is it wrong to measure with this code?

I would appreciate it if someone could let me know.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Maybe try installing one GPU at a time, into the same slot on motherboard